# Where do I place adverbs like "often"?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, word-order

Consider this sentence:

> He used to often visit her whenever she was alone.

Where are adverbs like 'often' placed in a sentence?

Comment: 'Often' does not add anything to the sentence: 'he used to visit her whenever she was alone' or 'He often visited her .. '

Comment: The sentence is unacceptable as 'often' and 'whenever' are in conflict rather than pleonastic; 'whenever' means 'each/every time'.  'He often used to visit her – whenever she was alone.' is admissible, as is 'He often used to visit her when she was alone.'  // I've placed 'often' before the verb string 'used to visit' here. Adverb placement is very tricky, but has been covered reasonably well on ELU before. As an example of the difficulties, 'Often, we went to the theatre' is fine but has a different emphasis from the unmarked  'We often went to the theatre'....

Comment: But 'Seldom, we went to the theatre' is unacceptable. 'We went to the theatre sometimes' is fine, but 'We went to the theatre never' is wrong. // Look up 'position of frequency adverbs'.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence as it stands has problems, as has been explained in the comments.

As to the question itself, in your example, the placement of "often" is up to you - there is no set rule: Use whatever sounds better to you, or is more suited to the context:

- He ***often*** visited her when she was alone.
- He visited her ***often***, when she was alone.
- ***Often***, he visited her when she was alone.

All viable choices in this case.

Other cases are not as simple. For example, to best of my knowledge (I am no expert), all these sentences are technically correct. However they differ greatly with respect to clarity and elegance:

- He ***never*** visited her when she had company. 
  ***Good.***
- He visited her ***never***, when she had company. 
  ***Awkward, perhaps unclear.***
- ***Never***, he visited her when she had company. 
  ***Very awkward.***